# AWS SSO 'no access error' with Custom SAML application

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I am trying to setup a Custom SAML 2.0 application with AWS SSO.
However I have the following error from network tab:

```
Status code 403
{"message":"No access","__type":"com.amazonaws.switchboard.portal#ForbiddenException"}
```

And this one displayed in the UI:

[image]

Two considerations that might cause this error:

1. My SP testing server is running in localhost
2. I am using self-signed certificates:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout myservice.key -out myservice.cert -days 365 -nodes -subj "/CN=localhost:9000"
```

If this still does not tell you anything then I will describe more below.

---

#### More details

This is the server code which is from the the library I am using

```golang
func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %s!", samlsp.AttributeFromContext(r.Context(), "cn"))
}

func main() {
    keyPair, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("myservice.cert", "myservice.key")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) // TODO handle error
    }
    keyPair.Leaf, err = x509.ParseCertificate(keyPair.Certificate[0])
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) // TODO handle error
    }

    idpMetadataURL, err := url.Parse("https://portal.sso.<my aws region>.amazonaws.com/saml/metadata/<some jewbrish id>")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) // TODO handle error
    }
    idpMetadata, err := samlsp.FetchMetadata(context.Background(), http.DefaultClient,
        *idpMetadataURL)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) // TODO handle error
    }

    rootURL, err := url.Parse("http://localhost:9000")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) // TODO handle error
    }

    samlSP, _ := samlsp.New(samlsp.Options{
        URL:            *rootURL,
        Key:            keyPair.PrivateKey.(*rsa.PrivateKey),
        Certificate:    keyPair.Leaf,
        IDPMetadata: idpMetadata,
    })
    app := http.HandlerFunc(hello)
    http.Handle("/hello", samlSP.RequireAccount(app))
    http.Handle("/saml/", samlSP)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

This server expose an endpoint where the IDP can get fetch my auto generated metadata.

```
curl -o metadata.xml http://localhost:9000/saml/metadata
```

Those are my metadata:

```
<EntityDescriptor xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" validUntil="2021-09-13T03:37:23.951Z" entityID="http://localhost:9000/saml/metadata">
  <SPSSODescriptor xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" validUntil="2021-09-13T03:37:23.951204335Z" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" AuthnRequestsSigned="false" WantAssertionsSigned="true">
    <KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
      <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <X509Data>
          <X509Certificate>xxxxxxxxxx</X509Certificate>
        </X509Data>
      </KeyInfo>
      <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"></EncryptionMethod>
      <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes192-cbc"></EncryptionMethod>
      <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"></EncryptionMethod>
      <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p"></EncryptionMethod>
    </KeyDescriptor>
    <SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://localhost:9000/saml/slo" ResponseLocation="http://localhost:9000/saml/slo"></SingleLogoutService>
    <AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="http://localhost:9000/saml/acs" index="1"></AssertionConsumerService>
  </SPSSODescriptor>
</EntityDescriptor>
```

I have uploaded those into AWS SSO and it correctly parsed it, the following in the configuration of my AWS SSO Custom application:

[image]

When I hit the `localhost:9000/hello` the application will be successfully redirected to the AWS SSO login console, but the that error happens.
I have also tested the application using this website: https://samltest.id/upload.php and it worked fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found the solution, the problem was in the attributes mapping, this is the configuration I had to use in order to make it work.

[image]

**Note the `transient` format option**, in my previous configuration it was `unspecified`

Comment: That was the one from me too. By inspecting the metadata emitted from AWS SSO, you can see this tag `<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</md:NameIDFormat>` which specificies the format AWS SSO support. Now, I'm not sure why would AWS propose the Subject assertion with another format than transient, and I also do not understand why support transient in the first place when it's not a opaque identifier...

Comment: In my case I am trying to use AWS SSO as the SAML provider and SP as OKTA. However I am getting the same error even after using ${user:subject} as transient. Please suggest .

Comment: For me was the "." instead of ":" between user and subject. I have struggled hours and hours until i see the mistake... period instead of colon...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The problem was my Service Provider configuration entityId didn't end in a "/", but my "Application SAML audience" on the AWS SSO page did end in a "/".

Even when I removed the "/" from my Application SAML Audience, I needed a "/" on the SP configuration.

Comment: Thanks, in my case was the format option in the attributes mapping

Comment: mappers on the side of keycloak or aws @Matteo, please?

Comment: @voidcraft on AWS, you can check the accepted solution

Answer (score 0):

Another cause of this helpful error can be if the ACS URL is not correct; in the configuration of a SAML app you specify an ACS URL 'Assertion Consumer Service' which is the callback once you obtain the assertion.

With Cognito/ALB/SSO setup this URL should end with saml2/idpresponse; something like **https**://idp.mydomain.com/**saml2/idpresponse**